# Change of variable in distribution

Tags: change-of-variable

I am a physics student. I am studying the [Maxwell-Boltzmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution) velocity distribution. Initially I began working with the distribution expressed in terms of momentum $p$, lets coll it $f_p(p)$, which is such that 
$$ n = f_p(p) \ dp $$ 
is the number of particles with momentum $ p \in (p, p + dp) $. In one problem I was asked to perform a change of variable from momentum to velocity using $ p = mv $. Initially I just replaced $ f_v (v) = f_p (mv) $ but I found this is wrong and the correct answer was 
$$ f_v(v) = f_p(mv) \frac{dp}{dv} .$$
After some investigation I understood why this is like this using physical arguments.

My question is if this is a characteristic of distributions in general. I mean, let $ f_x(x) $ to be a distribution and let $ x = g(y) $ to be a change of variable. Then 
$$ f_y (y) = f_x (g(y)) \frac{dg}{dy} $$
Is this a general property of distributions? If I have some object $ f_x(x) $ which I don't know if it is a distribution, can I assert that it is a distribution if I find it transforms like that? (similar to what happens with tensors, they are recognized by the way they transform).

Comment: I removed the tag *distribution-theory* since this question is not about that kind of distributions. This is rather a [density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Comment: Ok, sorry. I thought they were the same.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this transform property is that if $\Omega_p$ is a region in $p$-space then the number of particles with $p \in \Omega_p$ is given by
$$
n(\Omega_p) = \int_{\Omega_p} f_p(p) \, dp = \int_{\Omega_v} f_p(p) \, \frac{dp}{dv} dv = \int_{\Omega_v} f_v(v) \, dv,
$$
where $\Omega_v = \{ v \mid p(v) \in \Omega_p \}$ is the set of $v$ corresponding to a $p \in \Omega_p.$